# Haskell: human readable dates

Tags: haskell

Is there a library for turning human-readable relative dates like `"since yesterday"` and `"until Wednesday"` into `UTCTime`?

`friendly-time` looks like a good package, but I want something that can also give me `"until"`, `tomorrow`, and `next Saturday` times. Is there a more thorough package?

The fields in `Human Time Locale` are:

```
justNow :: String
secondsAgo :: String -> String
oneMinuteAgo :: String
minutesAgo :: String -> String
oneHourAgo :: String
aboutHoursAgo :: String -> String
at :: String -> String
daysAgo :: String -> String
weekAgo :: String -> String
weeksAgo :: String -> String
onYear :: String -> String
locale :: TimeLocale
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  It is a valid question, and now I want to know the answer myself....

Comment: The 14000th Haskell question!

Comment: I think some people don't like library questions like this on StackOverflow. I really don't mind them myself.

Comment: Not the downvoter but "questions to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam"

Comment: @jozefg- So what is the proper way to find a library or tool?  This is definitely an important part of programming, and this question is mentioning a particular function that happens to be very un-hoogle'able (HumanReadableDate->RelativeTime????)....  At any rate, why not downvote the opinionated answer or spam instead of the person with the question?

Comment: I would hate to get "next Saturday" as a time indication.

Comment: @n.m. What do you mean? "next Saturday" could be an input, not an output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That library is what you need.

[Dates](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dates)